# Linq Groupby, Union and Sum to aggregate data in multiple collections

Tags: c#, .net, linq

**Introduction**

**1.** I have a class StockVolume it has a property Points, which is of type `ObservableCollection<Point>`.

```
public class StockVolume
{
    public ...
    public ObservableCollection<Point> Points {get; set;}
    public ...
}
```

Point further has 3 properties of date, int, decimal

```
public class Point
{
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public int Pte {get; set;}
    public decimal Volume {get; set;}
}
```

**2.** I have another class StockAcceptance with a few properties,

```
public class StockAcceptance
{
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public int PTE {get; set;}
    public decimal BidVolume {get; set;}
    public decimal OfferVolume {get; set;}
}
```

**3.** The result needs to be loaded in the `ObservableCollection<Point>`

**Sample Data to explain the problem**

- The property Date and PTE is common

  - Group the stock acceptance by Date, PTE and sum the bidVolume and OfferVolume
  - Check if StockVolume has a date in StockAcceptance
  - If so, Sum the volume for the pte in StockVolume with the bidVolume and OfferVolume in StockAcceptance to arrive at the result.

[image]

I have started writing a solution but am using way too many temperory variables and for, foreach loops. This should be possible to implement in a better fashion using Linq, any Linq experts out there willing to share some inputs?

Comment: I believe that the last step is not correct: you're checking if `StockVolume` has Date *and* PTE in `StockAcceptance`, and then you're doing `Volume + BidVolume + OfferVolume`. Also, for the first example, the resulting Volume should be -19 and not -21, right?

Comment: Hi Andre, I will only Sum StockVolume and StockAcceptance if StockAcceptance has data for the dates in StockVolume. The volume will be -21 because newVolume = -20-(-4)-5 = -21.

Comment: Is the Date/PTE combo for the Points (in StockVolume) unique together?

Comment: PTE's will always be the ones specific above. Date will change. But together Date,PTE will be unique in StockVolume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Group the stock acceptance by Date, PTE and sum the bidVolume and OfferVolume
var groupStock=listStock.GroupBy(s=>new {s.Date,s.PTE})
                .Select(g=>new StockAcceptance
                       {
                            Date=g.Key.Date,
                            PTE=g.Key.PTE,
                            BidVolume=g.Sum(x=>x.BidVolume),
                            OfferVolume=g.Sum(x=>x.OfferVolume)
                       });
 StockVolume sv; 

 //get result you want:
 var result=from p in sv.Points
               join s in groupStock
               on new {Date=p.Date,PTE=p.Pte} equals new {Date=s.Date,PTE=s.PTE} into leftGroup
               from s in leftGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new Point
               {
                 Date=p.Date,
                 Pte=p.Pte,
                 Volume=s==null?p.Volume:p.Volume-s.BidVolume-s.OfferVolume
               };
//fill result into ObservableCollection<Point> 
ObservableCollection<Point> pCollection=new ObservableCollection<Point>(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have the following:

```
IEnumerable<StockAcceptance> accept = ...;
StockVolume volume = ...;
```

You should work from the innermost part, out.  The first thing you need to work on is the grouping of the stock acceptance:

```
var stockAccept = accept.GroupBy(a => new { a.Date, a.PTE },
    (k, g) => new { k.Date, k.PTE, 
        BidVolume = g.Sum(x => x.BidVolume), 
        OfferVolume = g.Sum(x => x.OfferVolume)
    });
```

This gives you a grouping on `Date` and `PTE` with the appropriate sums.

You can do the same on the `StockVolume` points as well:

```
var stockVolume = volume.GroupBy(v => new { v.Date, v.PTE },
    (k, g) => new {
        k.Date,
        k.PTE,
        Volume = g.Sum(x => x.Volume)
    });
```

Now you have the two groups which you can join on the key of the `Date` and `PTE` to get the final result:

```
IEnumerable<Point> result = stockAccept.Join(stockVolume, 
    o => new { o.Date, o.PTE },
    i => new { i.Date, i.PTE }, 
    (o, i) => new Point { 
        Date = o.Date, 
        PTE = o.PTE, 
        Volume = o.BidVolume + o.OfferVolume + i.Volume
    });
```